# Measure for a month and its previous using a named set SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I have a named set that returns the last 10 weeks from the current week. In the cube browser I get the value of a measure for each week. 
I want to create another measure that contains the value of the previous week returned by the named set. Something like this :

```
Weeks       Measure1     Measure2
Week 1         50           40
Week 2         35           50
Week 3         77           35
```

How to do this using MDX ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Measure2` will be a tuple of whatever measure you want to show - lets calls it `[Measures].[Revenue]` and the `currentmember` of the hierarchy used in the Weeks column lagged by 1.

I don't know the structure of your cube so you'll need to adjust the following:

```
(
  [Measures].[Revenue],
  [Date].[Calendar Week of Year].CURRENTMEMBER.LAG(1)
)
```